# Slow performance when rendering and filtering long list in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance

I've been developing an angular application and have a fairly long list (1600+ rows). When downloading the list, my application freezes and takes a really long time (+/- 10 seconds) to display the data.
I don't think this is right and have found some solutions on the internet. These tips however don't seem to affect the loading time.

While loading I had a look at the dev-tools in Google Chrome, which gave me this strange result:

[image: slow loading angular]

You can see that after loading the application freezes and takes more than 5 seconds to recover.

the function I call here is the following:

```
function loadInschrijvingen(activiteit_id, module_id, periode_id, groep_id){
    inschrijvingService.getInschrijvingenById(activiteit_id, module_id, periode_id, groep_id).then(function(response){
        applyInschrijvingen(response);
    });
}
```

the corresponding service function:

```
function getInschrijvingenById(activiteit_id, module_id, periode_id, groep_id){
    var request = $http({
    url: API_URL + 'inschrijvingen',
    method: 'GET',
    params: {activiteit_id: activiteit_id, module_id: module_id, periode_id: periode_id, groep_id: groep_id}
        });
   return (request.then(handleSuccess, handleError));
}
```

the url is just a normal DB query to fetch the rows.
Also filtering is a mess. It takes 5 seconds to search the rows, while only filtering the last name.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="zoeken op achternaam" ng-model="inschrijving.achternaam" ng-model-options="{debounce: 500}">


<tr class="fold new" ng-repeat="inschrijving in inschrijvingen | filter: inschrijving  track by inschrijving.id">
    <td>@{{$index+1}}</td>
    <td><span ng-click="toggle('edit', inschrijving.id)"></span></td>
    <td><span ng-click="confirmMail(inschrijving.id)" title="Inschrijvingsmail herzenden"></span></td>
    <td><span ng-click="confirmReminder(inschrijving.id)" title="Betalingsherinnering verzenden"></span></td>
    <td><span ng-click="confirmDelete(inschrijving.id)"></span></td>
    <td>@{{inschrijving.voornaam}} @{{inschrijving.achternaam}}</td>
    <td><a href="mailto:@{{inschrijving.email}}">@{{inschrijving.email}}</a></td>
    <td>@{{inschrijving.geboortedatum | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
    <td><i class="fa" ng-class="{'fa-male': inschrijving.geslacht == 'man', 'fa-female': inschrijving.geslacht == 'vrouw'}"></i></td>
    <td>@{{inschrijving.straat}}, @{{inschrijving.postcode}} @{{inschrijving.gemeente}} </td>
    <td>@{{inschrijving.gsm}}</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="inschrijving.betaald" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0" ng-checked="inschrijving.betaald == 1" ng-change="setState(inschrijving.id, 'postBetaald')"></td>
    <td>
    <select name="betalingswijze" id="betalingswijze" ng-model="inschrijving.betalingswijze" ng-change="setState(inschrijving.id, 'postBetalingswijze')">
        <option value="0" ng-selected="inschrijving.betalingswijze == 0">Geen</option>
        <option value="1" ng-selected="inschrijving.betalingswijze == 1">Cash</option>
        <option value="2" ng-selected="inschrijving.betalingswijze == 2">Overschrijving</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    <td><input class="bedrag" type="text" value="@{{inschrijving.bedrag}}" ng-model="inschrijving.bedrag" ng-change="setState(inschrijving.id, 'postBedrag')" ng-model-options='{ debounce: 1000 }'></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="inschrijving.fotos" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0" ng-checked="inschrijving.fotos == 1" ng-change="setState(inschrijving.id, 'postFotos')"></td>
    <td>
    <select name="tshirtmaat" id="tshirtmaat" ng-model="inschrijving.tshirtmaat" ng-change="setState(inschrijving.id, 'postTshirtmaat')" >
        <option value="" ng-selected="inschrijving.tshirtmaat == ''"></option>
        <option value="92" ng-selected="inschrijving.tshirtmaat == 92">92</option>      
        <option value="L" ng-selected="inschrijving.tshirtmaat == 'L'">L</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    <td>@{{inschrijving.opmerkingen}}</td>
</tr>
```

I'm really stuck with this, so if anyone could help me out?

Comment: 1600+ rows is a lot of HTML to render. I would add paging.

Comment: With paging, are the rows loaded in parts? I'll give it a try

Comment: That is one way of doing it yes. The other is to return the complete collection to the client and then query that dataset. UI Bootstrap is perfect for this. https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/pagination and https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead which will work nicely for your search.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest breaking down your application part by part, until you find the culprit.

- My first thing to try would be to remove the filter completely and see how that affects the load times/freezing
- Try removing any other requests on the page (e.g. the fonts you are loading etc) to rule out any external factors.

Comment: I already tried removing the font file, but no luck. I'll try and remove the filter to see how this affects the freezing